# Length of String Using Set Theory

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source, arithmetic, set-theory

From Wikipedia [Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers)

> The set N of natural numbers is defined as the smallest set containing
>   0 and closed under the successor function S defined by S(n) = n ∪ {n}.
>
> The first few numbers defined this way are 0 = {}, 1 = {0} = {{}}, 2 = {0,1} = {{},{{}}}, 3 = {0,1,2} = {{},{{}},{{},{{}}}}.

Using this definition of natural numbers count the length of a string.

**Input**  a string of characters from a-zA-Z of any length

**Output** the length of the string in set notation without separators

**Examples**

**Input**  Empty string

**Output** {}

**Input**  a

**Output** {{}}

**Input**  aaaa

**Output** {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}

For readability output for 'aaaa' with separators is

```
{ 
    {} 
    {{}} 
    {{} {{}} } 
    {{}   {{}}   {{} {{} } }   }
}
```

Conditions

1. No digits 0 to 9 to appear in the code;
2. No use of character code conversion to generate numbers;
3. No use of +-*/ for arithmetic calculations including increment and decrement;
4. No mathematical operations other than Boolean Logic;
5. Input string does not count in determining byte length;

**Winner** Shortest code length in bytes.

As this is my first question I hope I have made it clear and rigorous enough. Friendly advice accepted.

Comment: Hm, can you implement a recursive definition without calling `f(n-1)`?

Comment: I have a solution (non-optimal in terms of byte length) that does not use recursion. If A is an array then A.pop();f(A) is recursive.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: @jing3142 Kudos for implementing a solution yourself to make sure it's possible. +1 for great question.

Comment: What does the restriction to a-zA-Z mean? Should we detect whitespace/rubish? or should we just expect this and report the length of the string, regardles on the content?

Comment: @V-X the input string only consists of these characters, content is immaterial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>18</strike> 17 bytes)

```
'{'\{;.'}'++}/'}'
```

Takes input on the stack (so if run as a program, via stdin). Leaves the output as two strings on the stack (so if run as a program, the correct output is sent to stdout).

To leave a single string on the stack, either append `+` to concat, or use the alternative

```
'{}'\{;.);\'}'++}/
```

#### Dissection

```
# Stack: input-str
'{'\
# Stack: <0< input-str  where <0< means the string representing 0 without its final }
# Loop over each character of the input string
{
    # Stack: <n< char
    # Discard the input character
    ;
    # Concatenate two copies of <n< and a }
    .'}'++
}/
# Push the final } to the stack
'}'
```

Alternative:

```
# Stack: input-str
'{}'\
# Stack: <0> input-str  (where <0> means the string representing 0)
# Loop over each character of the input string
{
    # Stack: <n> char
    # Discard the input character
    ;
    # Duplicate <n> and remove the final '}'
    .);
    # Stack manipulations
    \'}'
    # Stack: <n>-less-final-'}' <n> '}'
    # Concatenate the three strings to get <n+1>
    ++
}/
```

#### Impact of the restrictions

If decrement were allowed, it would permit the 15-byte solution

```
'{}'\{;..,(/*}/
```

Answer (score 12):

## Haskell function, <del>35</del> 34 characters

```
f[]="{}";f(_:x)='{':f x++tail(f x)
```

## Haskell program with hardcoded input, <del>48 or 49</del> 47 or 48 characters

```
 f[]="{}";f(_:x)='{':f x++tail(f x);main=print$f"aaaa"
```

(47 characters if you don't mind extra quotes around the output; if you do, use `putStr` instead of `print` for a total of 48 characters)

## Haskell program, <del>51</del> 50 characters

```
f[]="{}";f(_:x)='{':f x++tail(f x);main=interact f
```

Comment: If you're OK with reversing the order, since it's a set, you can use: f[]="{}";f(_:x)='{':f x++(tail.f)x to save a character.

Comment: @isaacg Nice one. OP should tell us if he minds, though.

Comment: As its a set order does not matter so @isaacg 's suggestion is good

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3 - 64

```
o=['{}']
for a in input():o+=['{'+''.join(o)+'}']
print(o.pop())
```

If inlining the input is allowed:

## Python 2 - 54

```
o=['{}']
for a in'whatever':o+=['{'+''.join(o)+'}']
print o.pop()
```

Comment: Isn't raw-input() the method of inputing not the input string itself. Not being familiar with the range of languages possible I was disallowing the string length if something like w='aaaaaaaaaaaa' was necessary within the code. Sorry if not clear. Any help in re-wording question accepted.

Comment: I see. I'll rewrite my code accordingly. In general, however, I think you should just leave that line out. Essentially every language has an I/O system.

Comment: You can save a symbol by using `o[-1]` instead of `o.pop()`

Comment: "No digits 0 to 9 to appear in the code;"

Comment: A strange character-save for the first one: Initialize `o=[]`, which becomes `o=['{}']` after one step, and lengthen the input by one by replacing it with `'_'+input()`, cutting the space after `in`.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript 70 (chars)

```
s='';c=prompt().split('');while(c.pop()){s+='{'+s+'}'}alert('{'+s+'}')
```

This was my effort before setting the question. I would assume someone with more knowledge of Javascript than me can probably beat it.

Thank you Jan Dvorak and Peter Taylor for further reductions

## now 62

```
s='{';c=prompt().split('');while(c.pop())s+=s+'}';alert(s+'}')
```

## and now 61

```
s='{';for(c=prompt().split('');c.pop();)s+=s+'}';alert(s+'}')
```

**Explanation of Original Code**

set s to be empty

input string into c and split into an array

while it is possible to pop() a character from c do so and reset s=s{s} as successor

output current s but need to surround with set brackets.

Comment: You don't need braces after `while` (saves one character).

Comment: There's a 7-char saving without any more knowledge of JS required: initialise `s='{'` and ditch the two `'{'+`. (This then behaves like my GS solution). There's a further 1-char saving by using `for` instead of `while` and pulling in one of the two initialisations to the for-loop initialisation.

Comment: @peter-taylor not sure how you mean to apply for-loop. I have only ever used it for counting.

Comment: `for(a;b;c){d}` is directly equivalent to `a;while(b){d;c}` in most languages which have both. So while `for(;b;)` is identical to `while(b)` in effect and character count, `for(a;b;)` saves one char over `a;while(b)` and is identical in effect.

Comment: @peter-taylor +1 for very clear and concise explanation within a comment

Comment: @PeterTaylor Except c will still be called even if a continue statement is used in the body of the loop

Answer (score 3):

## J - <s>22</s> 20 char

```
'{','}' '{'&(,,~)~#
```

How this can be derived:

```
   #'123'                      NB. string length
3
   'Left' (,,~) 'Right'        NB. dyad to concat L,R,R
LeftRightRight
   '{' (,,~) '}'               NB. using braces
{}}
   '{'&(,,~) '}'               NB. bind left argument, now it's a monad
{}}
   '{'&(,,~) '{'&(,,~) '}'     NB. twice
{{}}{}}
   '{'&(,,~)^:2 '}'            NB. ^: is monad functional power
{{}}{}}
   '{'&(,,~)^:3 '}'            NB. any integer
{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   3 '{'&(,,~) '}'             NB. convenient feature of dyadic &
{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   '}' '{'&(,,~)~ 3            NB. swap argument order
{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   '}' '{'&(,,~)~ #'123'       NB. using string length
{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   '{', '}' '{'&(,,~)~ #'123'  NB. add final brace
{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   ('{','}' '{'&(,,~)~#) '123' NB. works as a verb
{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
```

Alternatively, this can be written `'{','{'&(,,~)&'}'@#`, meaning the same thing.

Usage:

```
   '{','}' '{'&(,,~)~# 'aaaa'
{{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
   f =: '{','}' '{'&(,,~)~#  NB. can be assigned to a function
   f 'VeryBig'
{{{{{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}{{{}}{}}{{}}{}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 64 characters

```
def f(s:String):String=s"{${s.tails.toSeq.tail.map(f)mkString}}"
```

Note the dual roles that both the braces and `s` play in this code.

EDIT: removed a digit

Comment: There is a digit in the code

Comment: @jing3142 Oops. Not any more.

Answer (score 2):

**Haskell - 35 charactes**

```
g[]="{}";g(_:x)=(init.g)x++g x++"}"
```

Solution is influenced by Jan Dvorak's one, but without reversing the order.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (44)

```python
s='{'
for _ in input():s+=s+'}'
print(s+'}')
```

At each step, `s` is the string representing the set with the final `}` removed. We create the set representing `n+1` from the set representing `n` via the relationship f(n+1) = f(n) ∪ {f(n)}. To implement the union with strings, we append the string for {f(n)}, which is exactly `s` but with the final `}` returned, and neglect to include the final `}` in the result. Finally, we add back a final `'}'` before printing.

If I may hardcode the string, the character count cuts down to 35 character, switching to Python 2 to save parantheses on the `print`.

```python
s='{'
for _ in'string':s+=s+'}'
print s+'}'
```

There might be a way to save the space after the `print` by doing something like `print'{'+s` with a reversed `s`, but this messes up with the `+=` appending on the right.

Answer (score 2):

## gs2, 12 bytes

```
7b 7d 05 27 a0 42 30 30 e4 43 2e 32
```

mnemonics:

```
"{}"
right-uncons @0 swap + + b5
rot length times
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 115 characters

```
StringReplace[ToString@Function[s,NestWhile[#~Append~#&,{},(s~Read~Character//StringQ)&]]@StringToStream@"test",", "->""]
```

The complete code as shown has 121 characters, but 6 of them are used for the input string (`"test"`) which, according to the rules, doesn't count.

Without the requirement that there are no delimiters, the code length could be reduced further by 24 characters; without explicit conversion to string then another 9 characters could be removed.

Comment: I thought that removing the need for deliminators, which are usually are required in set notation, I was helping to reduce code size. So if using them reduces your code size go ahead and use them.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 27, kind of cheating

```
a=*a
gets.chars{a=*a,a}
p a
```

Questionable things:

1. Output looks like `[[], [[]], [[], [[]]], [[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]]`
2. Most methods of input to ruby will include a trailing newline, which inflates the count by 1.

Comment: It should be perfectly legit if you `inspect` the array manually and `tr` the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Pure Bash, 54

```
f()([ $@ ]&&(a=`f ${@%?}`
echo $a{$a}))
echo {`f $@`}
```

Output:

```
$ ./strlenset.sh
{}
$ ./strlenset.sh a
{{}}
$ ./strlenset.sh aa
{{}{{}}}
$ ./strlenset.sh aaa
{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}
$ ./strlenset.sh aaaa
{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>45</s> <s>57</s> 48 bytes

```
"{"~~Fold[#~~"{"~~#~~"}"&,"",Characters@#]~~"}"&
```

---

A 36 bytes solution:

```
Fold[{##{##}}&@@#&,{},Characters@#]&
```

However, it uses some arithmetic calculations.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia 43

```
f(z)="{"foldl((x,y)->"$x{$x}","",{z...})"}"
```

The construct **{z...}** expands the string z into an array.  Fold loops over all elements of the array ignoring the contents and instead building up from the empty string.  The function **foldl** is available in Julia 0.30.

Sample Output

```
julia> f("")
"{}"
julia> f("aa")
"{{}{{}}}"
julia> f("aaaa")
"{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}"
julia> f("aaaaaa")
"{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 31 bytes

```
foldl(\s _->init s++s++"}")"{}"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi XE3 (264)

Ok I dont even come close to the other but it was fun to do :)
Probably overthinking it. Going to see if there is a better way to do this.

#### Golfed

```
uses System.SysUtils;var s,f:string;a:TArray<char>;b:TArray<string>;i,x:integer;begin readln(s);a:=s.ToCharArray;f:='{';setlength(b,Length(a));for I:=Low(a)to High(a) do begin s:='{';for x:=Low(b)to High(b)do s:=s+b[x];b[i]:=s+'}';f:=f+b[i];end;writeln(f+'}');end.
```

#### Ungolfed

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;
var
  s,f:string;
  a:TArray<char>;
  b:TArray<string>;
  i,x:integer;
begin
    readln(s);
    a:=s.ToCharArray;
    f:='{';
    setlength(b,Length(a));
    for I:=Low(a)to High(a) do
    begin
      s:='{';
      for x:=Low(b)to High(b)do
        s:=s+b[x];
      b[i]:=s+'}';
      f:=f+b[i];
    end;
    writeln(f+'}');
end.
```

#### Testing results

Tested strings with length 0..10

```
{}
{{} }
{{} {{}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}}} }
{{} {{}} {{}{{}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}}} {{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}{{}{{}}{{}{{}}}}}}}}}} }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. In my mind I was considering length as a mathematical operation as it returns a number and as is the use of a 'for' loop which involves counting.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl 5: 33 characters**

<strike>It's not quite clear which characters I should count as part of the solution. Probably not the `echo ... |` part because that's just used to feed a line in to stdin. Probably not the name of the perl binary, because you could rename that whatever you wanted.</strike>

So I've counted the command-line switches passed to perl, the quote marks wrapped around the Perl code, and the Perl code itself.

```
#                                1         2         3
#                     12  3456789012345678901234567890123
$ echo "aaaa" | perl -ple'$s.="{$s}"while s/.//;$_="{$s}"'
```

Also, [related](https://metacpan.org/pod/Number%3a%3aNatural%3a%3aSetTheory).

Comment: You should count `pl` as astandard, but you get `-e` and the quotes around the code for free. [Ref](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/194)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6: 37 characters

```
say ({"\{@_.join()\}"}...*)["(input string)".chars]
```

or from STDIN:

```
say ({"\{@_.join()\}"}...*)[get.chars]
```

`{"\{@_.join()\}"}...*` makes a lazy list of the set forms of the natural numbers, and we just grab the one we need with `get.chars`.

The lazy list might be more readably written:

```
-> *@prev { '{'~ @prev.join ~'}' } ... *
```

Which reads pretty similarly to the definition.

Answer (score 0):

### Dart: 85 characters

```dart
a(p,i)=>(--i).isNegative?p:a("$p{$p}",i);
main(s){print("{${a("",s.first.length)}}");}
```

(with extra newline for readability).

The requirement of not using "0" really bites, otherwise `.first` would be `[0]` and `(..).isNegative` would be `..<0`.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>171</s> <s>149</s> <s>147</s> 142 bytes

(Will likely be golfed further later)

```
n=prompt().split("");for(a=[];n.pop();)a.push(a.slice());alert(JSON.stringify({a:a})[R="replace"](/[^\[\]]/g,"")[R](/\[/g,"{")[R](/\]/g,"}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
+u++GG\}z\{\}
```

This is the golfed Pyth equivalent of @xnor's Python answer. Note that Pyth is newer than this question, so this answer is not eligible to win this challenge.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bu%2B%2BGG%5C%7Dz%5C%7B%5C%7D&input=aaaa&debug=0)

Comment: [`u+G]GlQY`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%2BG%5DGlQY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%22%0A%22a%22%0A%22aa%22%0A%22aaa%22%0A%22aaaa%22&debug=0)