# Print the power set of the power set ... of an empty set

Tags: code-golf, math, set-theory

Given a non-negative integer `n`, print the result of `P(P(...P({})))`, where the number of `P`'s is `n` (`P` is the power set function).

```
0 => {}
1 => P({})
2 => P(P({}))
3 => P(P(P({})))
n => P(f(n-1))
```

```
input   result
0       {}
1       {{}}
2       {{},{{}}}
3       {{},{{}},{{{}}},{{},{{}}}}
...
```

The result should only contain parentheses/brackets/braces and commas, spaces and newlines are allowed.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first question. I'd recommend sticking to our [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447) for code golf, rather than requiring the output using `{}`, because it means answers have to use a significant amount of bytes in converting their output to the required form. For future reference, we strongly recommend you first post your challenge ideas in [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140?answertab=active) to get feedback like this before you post them to the main site.

Comment: Also, I assume the output be in any order? For example, for input 2, both `{{{}},{}}` and `{{},{{}}}` are ok? And can the output contain duplicates, e.g. `{{{}},{},{}}`?

Comment: I would also look at the [sequence rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) (as this is extracting from the  sequence of repeated applications).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95035/36398)

Comment: @pxeger: Which of the standard I/O rules is related to the output using `{}`?  I looked through all 100+ and didn't see anything relevant.  Can you link directly to a single answer/poll, please?

Comment: @A.Rex Maybe the rule pxeger was really thinking about was the one to rule them all: [please avoid cumbersome I/O formats](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8077/58563).

Comment: @A.Rex well the ideal output format would be as any nested list kind of structure, not necessarily that string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 3 bytes

```
ŒP¡
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FkuPTgo4tHBJcVJy8fJDi45OerhzBkRiwUJjCAMA)

Using [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447); takes input from STDIN

Explanation:

```
  ¡         repeatedly apply
ŒP           the power set
             to nothing
              which defaults to 0
               which is turned into the range [1..0]
                which is []
```

---

If you insist on the `{{},{{}}}` formatting:

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 12 bytes

```
ŒP¡ŒṘ“[{]}”y
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700KzUnp3LBgqWlJWm6FluPTgo4tPDopIc7ZzxqmBNdHVv7qGFu5ZLipORiqIoFC40hDAA)

This could probably be shorter, but I'm not too interested in golfing boring formatting code.

Explanation:

```
ŒP¡ŒṘ“[{]}”y
  ¡                 repeatedly apply
ŒP                   the power set
   ŒṘ               convert to string representation
            y       translate
     “[{]}”          square brackets to curly braces
```

Comment: [3 bytes](https://tio.run/##ARYA6f9qZWxsef//xZJQwqH/wqLFkuG5mP8z)

Answer (score 8):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 8 bytes

```
{}1qR@C~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9W9r@61rAwyMG57n9whkN0dVGdQ2xtUV3gfwA)

```
{}   # Empty block
1    # Continuation takes top 1 elements of stack
qR@  # Quoted powerset
C~   # Continuation forever, printing all powersets
```

If you insist on getting a particular N

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 11 bytes

```
{}1qR@C~j!!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@U@b@61rAwyMG5LktR8X9whkN0dVGdQ2xtUV3gf2MA)

```
j!! # Reorder stack, get from block
```

And if you insist on comma-separated formatting add 8 bytes for

```
up' ',r~
```

Comment: Fixed, though the main block is not affected.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Nest[Subsets,{},#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98vtbgkOrg0qTi1pFinulZHOVbtv0t@dEBRZl5JdJ6Crp1CWnRebKyOQnWejoKBjoJJbex/AA)

In the notebook interface, the results are printed without spaces. But in TIO or the text-based interface, spaces are automatically added.

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

or 12

```
¾?(ṗ
```

### Explanation

```
¾?(ṗ
¾     Global array, empty at the start
 ?    Get input n
  (   Start loop n times
   ṗ  Powerset
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCvj8o4bmXIiwiIiwiMyJd)

### 12 bytes with the curly braces formatting:

(thanks to [@lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78850/lyxal))

```
¾?(ṗ)S¾S‛{}Ŀ
```

```
¾?(ṗ)S¾S‛{}Ŀ
¾?(ṗ)          The boring stuff
     S         Stringify the power-setted list
      ¾        Empty list -> `[]`
       ‛{}     Curly braces
          Ŀ    Transliterate, replace `[]` with the curly braces
```

The `P` prints the list with its python representation.
[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiwr4/KOG5lylTwr5T4oCbe33EvyIsIiIsIjMiXQ==)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 96 bytes

```
from itertools import*
f=lambda n:n and(chain(*(combinations(f(n-1),r)for r in range(n+1))))or()
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY5LCsJAEET3OUUve9QsgggSyF2cfMY0ZLqHTgfiWdxko3fyNkaJ-HYFr6i6P9PNeuFleUwW8vPrElQikHVqIsMIFJOo7bJQDT7WrQcuGTy32PSeGHfYSKyJvZHwiAE5L9xBXRAFBWJQz9cOeV-4FVF0287xY9DfOLkyg5UZKghI7huSEhvalIYOZ7dVf1ff)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 53 bytes

```hs
f=(!!)$iterate(\l->init l++[','|l/="{}"]++l++"}")"{}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBDoIwEAXQq3waEtpUi4nregJ3LpFFQ4bYODQIwwo4e5Hle58wf4k5597rojBlFJqCkH7z9RFTFLC1TXWpNq69WnfVWvsftStzKg8hJnjM9FsodYQSQxihx0VeMj0THHqD5ubcvc0H)

My first golf. Nothing particularly clever, uses the Fokker trick to deal with the base case.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: I don't think this does the task, unfortunately. The [output for taking power set n=5 times](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@98vtbgkOrg0qTi1pFinulZHOVbtv0t@dEBRZl5JdJ6Crp1CWnRebKyOQnWejoKBjoJpbex/AA) should be enormous, larger than roughly doubling the length of the string each time. It looks like you're outputting ordinals, similar to [this old challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25642/length-of-string-using-set-theory).

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 or <s>17</s> 11 bytes

```
yFY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9It8v9/YwA)

`F` - Repeat *Q* times, where *Q* is the implicit input:

`y` - powerset of

`Y` - empty list

#### With formatting

```
X`yFYQ"[]}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyKh0i0yUCk6trb6/39jAA)

`X..."[]}{` - convert each occurrence of `[` to `{` and each occurrence of `]` to `}`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 4 or 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Regular I/O using `[]` instead of `{}` and spaces after the commas would be 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):

```
¯IFæ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0HpPt8PL/v83BgA) or [verify the first few test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9ybJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w@t93M7vOx/rc5/AA).

Strict I/O format is 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage):

```
¯IFæ}"ÿ"„[]„{}‡ðK
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0HpPt8PLapUO71d61DAvOhZIVNc@alh4eIP3///GAA) or [verify the first few test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/W9ybJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w@t93M7vKxW6fB@pUcN86JjgUR17aOGhYc3eP/X@Q8A).

**Explanation:**

`"ÿ"` on lists only works in the legacy version of 05AB1E (built in Python), and unfortunately not in the new 05AB1E version (built in Elixir). I'm not sure how to do this challenge in the new version of 05AB1E, which lacks any form of `toString` builtin on lists..

```python
¯        # Push an empty list: []
 IF      # Loop the input amount of times:
   æ     #  Pop the current list, and push its powerset
         # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)

¯IFæ     # Same as above
  }      # Close the loop
   "ÿ"   # Convert the (nested) list to a string
„[]„{}‡  # Transliterate all "[" to "{" and "]" to "}"
ðK       # Remove all spaces
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 71 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n and f(n-1,1<<k)or[f(0,i+1)for i in range(k)if~-k>>i&1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDkAwDADQX@lJ2phEw0nwI@IwoTSjk8XFxa/Pe/f7HNGanGU4/bWsHsyFgTsDbysIWsWO@z5QTJNg7bRkkphAQQ2St33DQCpfFcZRC57zndQeFGyJ8g8)

Adapts [pxeger's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248716/) to [Enumerate all pure sets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/248715/).

Computes the pure set corresponding to \$^n2-1\$ in the binary-encoding enumeration, which consists of the \$^{n-1}2\$ distinct sets with rank less than \$n\$.

Comment: @MarcMush that happens to coincide for n=4, but in general \$^n2\ne2^{2^n}\$

Comment: alright, I will revisit my answer

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES10), 95 bytes

Assuming a strict output format:

```javascript
f=(n,a=[])=>n?f(n-1,a.reduce((a,x)=>a.flatMap(y=>[y,[...y,x]]),[[]])):(g=a=>`{${a.map(g)}}`)(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBCoMwEEDRfc/RxQyMQ213hdgTeIIQcNBEWmwiaotBPHuabXHzF4//kq/M7fQcl8KHzqbkFHgSpQ2qyj8c@KIk4cl2n9YCCK3Zhd0gSy0jRFXpSJqZI63GIGmdi3folaiq2c6b8Dt/Pe57gyCY2uDnMFgeQg8OLoinfykPcj3IDTH9AA)

---

## JavaScript (ES10), 71 bytes

Returning an array of arrays:

```javascript
f=(n,a=[])=>n?f(n-1,a.reduce((a,x)=>a.flatMap(y=>[y,[...y,x]]),[[]])):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcjBCsIwDADQu1@SQBac3oTOL/ALQg@ha0Up6dimrF9fd5Vd3uG99atLmF/T2lkZY2vJgZE68egGuyewriflOY6fEAGUtv2VU9b1oRNUN0glYeZKm/dIIrt40xaKLSVHzuUJCc6Ip//pD3M5zBWx/QA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 72 bytes

```factor
[ { } [ all-subsets ] repeat unparse " "without "}{""},{"replace write ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsIwEIfxvU/xJ7O6uOkDiIuLOEmHazjbwzQJlytFS589FtePH9@LvCWtj/v1djlhJBsOPo2dRNqy@IKeIysF@ZJJigVZ2eyTVaKhsBWUHMRMYg9JeLNGDjg3zbGpTyxY8QSFsC9T99ctlDOTYYqZtDAc3Cw2pMng1sW5dbe4jQTyjFnFGG3126H@AA)

As written.

---

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 30 bytes

```factor
[ { } [ all-subsets ] repeat ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDsIwDAXQPaf4F6ALGxwAsbAgpqqDGxmwSJ3IdgdAnD30je9OOar12/V8OR2wUDyHXJdZlLaW7HiwslGRD4VUdTTjiHcz0cCLTbngmNI@9RFf/DCCStn5OjuHY4JxYwpMPW@Pof8B)

With standard I/O rules.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 206 bytes

```c
#define P putchar
f(i,s,c){P(123);for(s=0;i;++s,i>>=1)if(i&1){f(s);if(i>1)P(44);}P(125);}s,i;main(c,v)char**v;{sscanf(v[1],"%d",&c);for(s=!!c--;c>0;--c)s=1<<s;P(123);for(;i<s;){f(i++);if(s>i)P(44);}P(125);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NCsIwEITvPoVWlGyTgPHntG2eoXfxUFaje7BKV3spPntMBEE8DQMz8w3ZM1GM8@MpcHeaNtP780GXtp8ExUYMwdgot94AhluvpF4ho9Zi2PvaAafQ0sEYlABm4x00arsFfOXWLmmK4rXlTpEZIA@X5YCjCLVdUMPeHUyxOBZmSV/CbEbWIvkVWksgtasqwZ8PyMlnJGv9gYrnf2iMcfMG)

Comment: You can shave a few bytes: 
`for(;i<s;){f(i++);if(s>i)P(44);}` --> `for(;i<s;)f(i++),(s>i)&&P(44);`
the same trick can be used to shorten `if(i&1){f(s);if(i>1)P(44);}`

Comment: Building on @MatteoC. [178 bytes](https://tio.run/##Lc6xDoIwEAbg3aeQkJA7KGhx86i@QnfjQCo1NwiGEkICPHutynDD/w/ffyZ/GuN9/Ggst81ew1QUBb57bgcL8YQ7CyycMDjbrgenIg0zEhMfVIkuU5zIqwWHgqtyWTQIPEvSsCKtTjC9am7BiBGDl6YjzUbVQ8cw3uQdaSMjQ3luLkdCp2RVuV//3wkhXJJ8YQyvZBluuvf@9AE "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: It looks like you're not using the 3rd parameter in f, so you can get rid of it for -2 bytes

Comment: Since this has undefined behaviour for `n > 5` maybe it's fine to do it like [this](https://tio.run/##LczBCoJAEMbxe09RCDKju4bWIRqXXmHv0UEmt@aQhRsiqM@@qXT4Dn8@@LF@MIcQ3WsnTb210GdZhp9Wmq@DqMeNA1EeB/duwZudhQFJSPamQJ8aifOLA49KymIcLSg852RhQpo8vSppgFWH/KzaJOloRYgNJN01v6HW@ngi9CYvS0/Lt@o8x7w4Xjh0wGmKfzOEcPgB) for 166 bytes, which wouldn't work for `n > 9` anyway

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

*Ties [pxeger's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248448) and [math junkie's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248457) for #1.*

```
ćFæ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SLvb4WX//0cbxwIA) Takes input as a singleton list, and outputs with square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
Øᶦ{Sa
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FisOz3i4bVl1cOKS4qTkYqggTBIA)

```
Øᶦ{Sa
Ø       Empty list
 ᶦ{     Iterate
   Sa   All subsets
```

Since Nekomata is a non-deterministic language, the built-in `S` (`\subset`) returns any subset non-deterministically instead of all subsets in a list. This is helpful for many other challenges, but not this one. We have to add an `a` (`\allValues`) to get the power set.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 26 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ≔ＥＸ²Ｌυ⪫{}⪫Φυ﹪÷κＸ²ν²,υ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwEEX3niJkNQNxU5ddCSIorfQKMY1tMJ2ENKkL8ewxAXEz8/j8eaNmGZSTNueHCwwupIJeNEU9FvYp3tJy1wEQkR3X1UwEvfQwuFcJG8E6TVOcISEKdnWGgL8//IdnY2NpJcF6NybrijCezGZGDU/B/gqqt00dXHCsO2G7G4KhWP746m5zPuT9Zr8) Link is to verbose version of code. Extremely inefficient; do not try `n=4` unless you have a lot of patience (will time out on TIO). Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ
```

Repeat `n+1` times...

```
≔ＥＸ²Ｌυ⪫{}⪫Φυ﹪÷κＸ²ν²,υ
```

... replace the predefined empty list with its formatted powerset.

```
⊟υ
```

Output the last element.

21 bytes using Python list formatting:

```
ＦＮ≔ＥＸ²ＬυΦυ﹪÷κＸ²ν²υ⭆¹υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETvfsUedyEerMeeBBEEKwW/IG1jGoxJSXfr56fJxcsMPObNOOs0Ru1zfscEeA@L8FO@g0lIBJd1dTZgpxfs46@wRsHDBMszCpGCm/NcqCjo4iQ@Fp@vbnOTwY@CvxLqtqGaQu2hTy4wvriUrdeniqnN@ZyPm98B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times...

```
≔ＥＸ²ＬυΦυ﹪÷κＸ²ν²υ
```

... replace the predefined empty list with its powerset.

```
⭆¹υ
```

Pretty-print the list.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 205 bytes

```
\(n,z=paste0,b=\(x)z('{',x,'}'),p=\(x,e=el(strsplit(x,',')),l=lapply(e,\(i)c(i,NA)),g=do.call(expand.grid,l),d=\(v)z(na.omit(v),collapse=','),a=apply(g,1,d))d(b(a))){s='';for(i in seq_len(n)){s=p(s)};b(s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY9BasMwEEWv4kVBMzA1CXRRGmbRC_QEhiJbshFMZUVSgxOTk3TjFnqcHqC3qZy03cwwfz6P_9_e4_LR8-dr7m_vv78a8HTioFO2G2q5gQlPoGZFE6mzQgqrRJatQMoxBXG53IoUIgmLDkGOYKkBhx04enos-sBmrDstAnYK2pt6iM6QIJkCOxS-1_X4UkAHpG6UAkmWVyRpvgIH2pJBNNCCRsQ5sVK7fozgKuerZPfPYj34yydAwvOuXedvqZt_5-bhDucQnc9wqVgSVn2Jin_eZbnuHw)

A naive implementation of powerset for comma-delimited strings in R, using `seq_len` instead of `1:n` to handle the n = 0 case correctly.

Comment: @evanstar3 you proposed an edit to change this to a C-language implementation that I believe is your own. I believe that implementation should be an answer so you receive due credit.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 34 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⎕json{⌿∘⍵¨↓⌽⍉2⊥⍣¯1⊢¯1+⍳2*≢⍵}⍣⍵⊢⍬}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37UNzWrOD@v@lHP/kcdMx71bj204lHb5Ec9ex/1dho96lr6qHfxofWGj7oWAUntR72bjbQedS4CKqsFSgApoMSj3jW1AA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQFYwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Marked as community wiki because the power set function has been taken from APLCart.

Comment: `{⌿∘⍵¨↓⍉a⊤⍳×/a←2⍴⍨≢⍵}` for powerset

Answer (score 0):

## BQN, 17 bytes

```
{(⥊(↕2˘)/¨<)⍟⟨⟩}
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgeyjipYoo4oaVMsuYKS/CqDwp4o2f8J2VqeKfqOKfqX0KRiAz)

Powerset composed x times on empty set.

---

## BQN, 42 bytes

```
{{'⟨':'{';'⟩':'}';}¨•Repr(⥊(↕2˘)/¨<)⍟⟨⟩}
```

[Try it here!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge3sn4p+oJzoneyc7J+KfqSc6J30nO/Cdlal9wqjigKJSZXByKOKliijihpUyy5gpL8KoPCnijZ/wnZWp4p+o4p+pfQpGIDM=)

Strictly formatted variant.

If `⟨⟩` count as valid brackets, then simply remove `{'⟨':'{';'⟩':'}';}¨` for a 22-byte solution.